# Can you add -ness to the word "blasé"?

Tags: grammaticality

I tried searching the word up. Some results did pop up but I doubt the accuracy of the sources. Does anyone know the answer to this??

Comment: "Can" you?  Yes.  "Should" you?  No.

Comment: Please ***include*** the research. It's a question of adding mabe a link and a sentence or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you did say "blaséness", people would understand what you meant (or at least, everyone who knows what "blasé" means would understand what you meant). However, I don't think it's really a "proper" word, so it might sound a little strange or awkward to some.

Maybe "indifference" or "jadedness" would serve better.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You should not do that. "Blasé" is, it hardly needs to be said, a French borrowing, while "-ness" is a quintessentially Anglo-Saxon suffix. They just don't mesh, which is why writers have seldom, if ever, put the two together and why it will look odd if you choose to do so. If you want to convey through a noun the idea of being bored and tired of life but also to impart a French flavor, consider "ennui".